excel: automatically update the single cell value of seconnd sheet when I drag down column of the first sheet
I wish when I drag down the column Q at the sheet 1, the value of the single cell B5 at sheet 2 (sheet name:c_calculated) will be automatically updated to the repsected row value from the column N at shee 1.
For example, if I have drag down to row 7 of column Q at the sheet 1, the value at cell B5 of sheet 2 will be shifted to the value from row 7 of column N at the sheet 1.
If I have drag down to row 19 of column Q at the sheet 1, the value at cell B5 of sheet 2 will be shifted to the value from row 19 of column N at the sheet 1.
Could our friends give me guideline on this?
My file can be downloaded throughed the following link, after it is guided to the link page, just click file->download->microsoft excel (located at the top left corner of the page)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1elsI_WsGmeaJ-JRJgzjnNBgekgPGYAZA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104482621481585823648&rtpof=true&sd=true
Kind Regards
Unclear about the method to achieve that goal

I'm not sure what you mean by drag down. Are you editing the cell and then want to update the other sheet?

Drag down means that I quickly copy formulas into adjacent cells by dragging the fill handle. As shown on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdyGu2Ccz2Q

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do, and what problem is arising. Could you split the question into 3 sections, i.e. what you're trying to achieve, what you've attempted, and what didn't work?
